# Using Layout Service with master db

Tags: jss, layout-service

We have a requirement to fetch the item fro the `master` db. JSS is always pointing to the `web` db.

We tried to add the query parameter as `sc_content=master` in the Layout Service, but still the Layout Service is pointing to the `web` db.

In the JSON response we are seeing as `databaseName:web`

**Sample URL**

```
http://jssapp/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_content=master&item={4ADCE242-7382-47DD-8FC5-7FF2E6607C42}&sc_apikey={699E87BB-E988-4815-A53B-EE4B8A177F47}&sc_device=mobile&sc_lang=en
```

Comment: Be aware that it is common that in a scaled environment that the CD has no connection with the master DB, your requirement is actually awkward.. also think of another solution, scheduled publish e.t.c

Answer (score 2):

JSS Layout Service take a database based on the current site which is resolved by a domain name in your URL. Your site, that stays behind `jssapp` domain, is configured to use the `web` database. Update your site settings to use the `master` database and `JSS` also will use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can patch the config based on your hostname as below with the database.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The JSS Service considers the database from the config file that we put into Sitecore instance by "jss deploy config" command. This file you can find out in jss application or in Sitecore instance - /App_config/Include/zzz/[appname].config.
Basically that file contains the site definition with database attribute.